# Ruby / Nokogiri XSLT transform and external function

Tags: ruby, xslt, nokogiri

I'd like to know if Ruby / Nokogiri has implemented external function uses within XSLT.

If yes, what's the syntax ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 4):

You can use ruby functions in your XSLT files by:

```
myfuncs = Class.new do
  def func1(a, b)
    # do processing here
  end
end

Nokogiri::XSLT.register "http://example.com/functions", myfuncs
```

In the XSLT file, don't forget to add this to the root element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:my="http://example.com/functions" extension-element-prefixes="my">
```

You can then use the function like this:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:value-of select="my:func1(@a, @b)"/>
</xsl:template>
```